# Setting up wordpress on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, apache2

I have dual-booted my Win7 laptop with Ubuntu 12.04, and I'm trying to install Wordpress. I have installed Apache2, Mysql-Server, and Wordpress and I keep getting asked for ftp credentials when I try and install plugins/themes. I know how to install the themes etc. manually by downloading and unzipping into the correct folders, but this isn't a permanent solution.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling everything but I keep getting faced with tutorials on setting up virtual hosts and I'm not sure if I need to have one?

Can anyone point me to an easy to follow (for beginners) tutorial from scratch? Or tell me if I'm missing something?

My Wordpress site needs to be moved from local machine to a server when it's finished (I don't know the server yet so I can't just start using it) so I need it to be as easy to use as possible.

Comment: I'd use this search query to investigate the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwordpress%5D+ftp+credentials+is%3Aquestion

Comment: Thanks, I kept unistalling and reinstalling and I'm not quite sure what I did but it's working, and stopped asking for ftp too thankfully!! I'll bookmark your link for future reference just in case!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are available tutorials for that.

**Step 1-**

Installing the server-

1. [Installing the server](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-install-lamp-on-ubuntu)
2. [Initial Setup (**Optional**)](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-14-04)

**Step 2-**

Installing Wordpress-

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-on-ubuntu-14-04